# Adding UISegmentedControl in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want to add the `UISegmentedControl` below the `searchBar` and above the TableView of `UISearchDisplayController`. Currently `UISearchDisplayController` only shows its `tableView` under its `SearchBar`.

But i want to add a `UISegmentedControl` below the `SearchBar` so that I have `SearchBar` on the top, after `SearchBar` I have a `UISegmentedControl` and below that `UISegmentedControl` I have `UITableView`. Is that any way to do this using `UISearchDisplayController` or i have to make my own `SearchDisplayController` that have its own `SearchBar` , `UISegmentedControl` and `TableView`?

any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Enable `ShowScopeBar` and add as many as segments by adding scop titles and handle them by following method

**By Code**

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
    [searchBar setScopeButtonTitles:@[@"button1",@"button2"]];
    [[self view] addSubview:searchBar];
```

**By XIB**

[image]

**Delegate method to handle scope button action**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope{


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a view in table

```
UIView *viewsearch=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-10, 320,83)];
    [self.tblname addSubview:viewsearch];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:revealController.panGestureRecognizer]

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5, 320, 40)];
    searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    searchBar.delegate=self;
    [searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(249/255.0) green:(9/255.0) blue:(99/255.0) alpha:1]];
    searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search items e.g. jacket";
```

Addsearchbar view in that view.

```
    [viewsearch addSubview:searchBar];

    searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Use UISegmentedControl in this searchview.

```
    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"General", @"Near me", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(50,53, 225, 22);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(MySegmentControlAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(249/255.0) green:(10/255.0) blue:(99/255.0) alpha:1];

    segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [viewsearch addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for my Problem that i added the UISegmentedControl as a Header of TableView of UISearchDisplayController. In this way it just looked like that i have added a UISegmentedControl Separately under the searchBar of UISearchDisplayController.

Thank You every one who tried to help.